# Leyendas en bokeh con latex

Tags: python, python-3.x, latex

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de poder escribir las leyendas en Bokeh con formato LateX. Lo digo porque es bastante frustrante escribir `f(x)=x^3-1`, queda muy pobre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aún no esta soportada, pero esta en proceso como lo dice la documentación: [bokeh.models.axes](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.1/docs/reference/models/axes.html).

Mira estos pull request para que sigas el avance:

- [Add label annotation #3956](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/3956)
- [Support latex labels #647](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/647)